# Json.NET works in editor but throws error after building

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to deserialize JSON into list of Faction class. It works as it should in editor, but when I build and run the game it throws following error:

JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[PlomekStudios.Factions.FactionType,System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Here is my code:

```
public class FactionsManager : Singleton<FactionsManager>
{
    [SerializeField] private TextAsset baseFactionsData;
    public List<Faction> factions {get; private set;}

    protected override void Awake() 
    {
        base.Awake();
        factions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Faction>>(baseFactionsData.text);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Faction
{
    public string name;
    public FactionType factionType;
    public Dictionary<FactionType, int> factionRelations;
}
```

And here is my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Player",
    "factionType": "Player",
    "factionRelations": [
      {
        "Key": "Enemy",
        "Value": -100
      },
      {
        "Key": "Orbicom",
        "Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Key": "BodzanovaCo",
        "Value": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Enemy",
    "factionType": "Enemy",
    "factionRelations": [
      {
        "Key": "Player",
        "Value": -100
      },
      {
        "Key": "Orbicom",
        "Value": -100
      },
      {
        "Key": "BodzanovaCo",
        "Value": -100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Orbicom",
    "factionType": "Orbicom",
    "factionRelations": [
      {
        "Key": "Player",
        "Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Key": "Enemy",
        "Value": -100
      },
      {
        "Key": "BodzanovaCo",
        "Value": -20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "BodzanovaCo",
    "factionType": "BodzanovaCo",
    "factionRelations": [
      {
        "Key": "Player",
        "Value": 0
      },
      {
        "Key": "Enemy",
        "Value": -100
      },
      {
        "Key": "Orbicom",
        "Value": -20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a dotnet console project(**not Unity**) with `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`(**not JsonConvert**) to test the JSON string you provided, and I'm encountering a similar problem.

### Your Test String

```
string str = """
[
{
    "name": "Player",
    "factionType": "Player",
    "factionRelations": [
    {
        "Key": "Enemy",
        "Value": -100
    },
    {
        "Key": "Orbicom",
        "Value": 0
    },
    {
        "Key": "BodzanovaCo",
        "Value": 0
    }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Enemy",
    "factionType": "Enemy",
    "factionRelations": [
    {
        "Key": "Player",
        "Value": -100
    },
    {
        "Key": "Orbicom",
        "Value": -100
    },
    {
        "Key": "BodzanovaCo",
        "Value": -100
    }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Orbicom",
    "factionType": "Orbicom",
    "factionRelations": [
    {
        "Key": "Player",
        "Value": 0
    },
    {
        "Key": "Enemy",
        "Value": -100
    },
    {
        "Key": "BodzanovaCo",
        "Value": -20
    }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "BodzanovaCo",
    "factionType": "BodzanovaCo",
    "factionRelations": [
    {
        "Key": "Player",
        "Value": 0
    },
    {
        "Key": "Enemy",
        "Value": -100
    },
    {
        "Key": "Orbicom",
        "Value": -20
    }
    ]
}
]
""";
```

### Test Code

Here's my code to test your string. Since the json string was too long and is bad for readability, I seperate it from the code.

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

string str = "" // Paste your json string here

var collection = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Faction>>(str);
System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', collection[0].factionRelations.Select(p=>(p.Key,p.Value))));
System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', collection[1].factionRelations.Select(p=>(p.Key,p.Value))));
System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', collection[2].factionRelations.Select(p=>(p.Key,p.Value))));

public class Faction
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string factionType { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> factionRelations { get; set; }
}
```

I'm encountering the same issue as you are. The compiler tells me that json string cannot be converted to `Dictionary<string,int>` for `factionRelations`.

My thought is that this might be due to the default behavior of how `JsonSerializer` tries to parse and convert `Dictionary`. The conversion fails because we are providing a JSON string with an incompatible format.

### Modified Test String

```
string str = """
[
{
    "name": "Player",
    "factionType": "Player",
    "factionRelations": {
        "Enemy":-100,
        "Orbicom":0,
        "BodzanovaCo":0
    }
},
{
    "name": "Enemy",
    "factionType": "Enemy",
    "factionRelations": {
        "Player":-100,
        "Orbicom":-100,
        "BodzanovaCo":-100
    }
},
{
    "name": "Orbicom",
    "factionType": "Orbicom",
    "factionRelations": {
        "Player":0,
        "Enemy":-100,
        "BodzanovaCo":-20
    }
},
{
    "name": "BodzanovaCo",
    "factionType": "BodzanovaCo",
    "factionRelations": {
        "Player":0,
        "Enemy":-100,
        "Orbicom":-20
    }
}
]
""";
```

Here, I have converted the JSON string for `factionRelations` from an array to an object by using curly braces `{}` and adopting the `"Key": value` pattern instead of the previous `"Key": "keyname", "Value": 0` structure.

I'm not sure if the same solution will work for `JsonConvert`, but you can try it out to see if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tbh not sure why it should work in the editor at all in the first place.

What you have there in your JSON is indeed **not** a `Dictionary` but rather a `List`/array!

A dictionary in JSON would look like e.g.

```
"factionRelations" : {
    {
        "someKey" : someValue
    },
    ...
}
```

changing

- `[ ]` → `{ }`
- `"key":"someKey", "Value":someValue` → `"someKey":someValue`

In general throw your json into [Json2Csharp](https://json2csharp.com) if not sure about your JSON data structures.

---

If modifying your JSON itself accordingly [as mentioned by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76751320/7111561) is not an option you could instead use a custom constructor and do

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Faction
{
    public string name;
    public FactionType factionType;
    public Dictionary<FactionType, int> factionRelations = new Dictionary<FactionType, int>();

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Faction(string name, FactionType factionType, List<FactionRelation> factionRelations)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.factionType = factionType;
        
        foreach(var factionRelation in factionRelations)
        {
            this.factionRelations[factionRelation.Key] = factionRelation.Value;
        }

        // or using System.Linq
        //this.factionRelations = factionRelations.ToDictionary(factionRelation => factionRelation.Key, factionRelation => factionRelation.Value);
    }
}

public class FactionRelation
{
    public FactionType Key;
    public int Value;
}
```

---

If you also need the conversion **to** json you could instead rather implement a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)